# Timer not working in VB.NET 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

Well, i'm making a timer (to be specific, it is an *Internet Café Standalone Timer* that is on Visual Basic 2010 with a target framework of **.NET Framework 4.5**.

Now, there is a mini form that shows your: `time start, time out, minutes (total minutes of your rent), and your time left.` I've managed to get the content of **time start** on my `Main.vb`, same as the time out, and the minutes (see the code reference later). Now, i'm trying to get the time left that is constantly updating every minute. Output is like: "`33 minutes left`"

`Main.vb`:

```
        If TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.userpass Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enjoy!", "...")
            dtFuture = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(min.Text).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
            Limited.currtime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
            Limited.timeout.Text = dtFuture
            Limited.minutes.Text = min.Text
            Limited.Timer1.Interval = 1
            Limited.Timer1.Start()
            Limited.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            ...
        End If
```

`Limited.vb` (this is the form when you have limited time, not *open* time):

```
Public Class Limited
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim foo As New TimeSpan
        Dim dtfuture As New DateTime
        Dim timecurrent As TimeSpan = dtfuture.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        Dim timeCheckIn As String = Format(timecurrent, "HH:mm:ss")
        dtfuture = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes.Text)

        If Timer1.Interval <> 100 Then Timer1.Interval = 100
        If DateTime.Now > dtfuture Then
            timelft.Text = "Time's up!"
            block.Show()
            Timer1.Stop()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            foo = dtfuture - DateTime.Now
            ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timeCheckIn)
            timelft.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}", _
                              foo.Hours, foo.Minutes, foo.Seconds, foo.Milliseconds)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Label3.Text = TimeOfDay
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' hide app in to the taskbar

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Well, I have the time that the rent started and the time that he will gonna stop, but the timer or the 'label' doesn't shows up.

Comment: And they're definitely visible at the front of the form, not hidden behind anything? Font colour different to background, etc?

Comment: Your `dtfuture` does not have the correct value in `Timer1_Tick`. Your `dtfuture` is always equal to `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes.Text)`. So `If DateTime.Now > dtfuture Then` will always be false and time is never up.

Comment: @ProGrammer No they aren't

Comment: @jetstream96 Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @astronomicalXoom Can't write a proper answer now. I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @jetstream96 any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `dtfuture` does not have the correct value in Timer1_Tick. I am not sure what `ts` means so you may need to modify that part yourself.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim foo As New TimeSpan

    ' This is when time will be up.
    Dim dtfuture As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(timeout.Text)

    ' I have no idea what these variables do. Not sure what "ts" below means.       
    Dim timecurrent As TimeSpan = dtfuture.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    Dim timeCheckIn As String = Format(timecurrent, "HH:mm:ss")

    ' The If in original code is unnecessary.
    Timer1.Interval = 100

    If DateTime.Now > dtfuture Then
        timelft.Text = "Time's up!"
        block.Show()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        foo = dtfuture - DateTime.Now
        ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timeCheckIn)
        timelft.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}", _
                          foo.Hours, foo.Minutes, foo.Seconds, foo.Milliseconds)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and it display a error: "Value of 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to 'Date'."

Comment: @astronomicalXoom Sorry, that should be `DateTime.Parse`. I updated the answer.